# Text using PIL on Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, draw

I am trying to use the PIL module and ImageDraw to add text on an image.
I want to add this text at a given absciss but I want to use 2 different fonts. The problem is that I do not manage to use 2 types of front in the draw.text. To imagine the situation I want to obtain something as in the following photo with 2 different fonts in the same display.
Do you have some ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can load and reference different fonts in PIL using

```py
font1 = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeMono.otf", size=20)
font2 = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeMono.otf", size=25)
```

and use it in a single draw call like

```py
draw.text((5, 5), "Hello", font=font1)
```

You can use `font1.getsize("Text contents")` or `font1.getsize_multiline("Multiline \n text")` in order to find out how much space you need to render the text with that font. Using this, you should be able to continue with the new font at that offset. Doing this is not very ergonomic, and probably has a lot of edge cases that need to be handled.

You might be better off with a different library that can render markup text. Perhaps something like pango or cairo, or even LaTeX if you want it to be fancy.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time,  that was king of my idea but it is ot very suitable for centering and so on. Can I modify directly images and add text with pango, Cairo or Latex ? I Don't know these modules on python